# How to terminate a console mode app from a BackGroundWorker

Tags: c#

I am creating one BackgroundWorker and inside its DoWork function I have the following code:

```
        foreach (string newFilepath in newFilesPath)
        {
                        if (!File.Exists(encryptedFilePath))
                        {
                            encryptedFiles.Add(encryptedFilePath);
                            Helper.SendErrorMail(null, "Could not find encrypted file.", encryptedFilePath);
                            Application.Exit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Helper.Count_DataFeeds++;
                            File.Delete(newFilepath);
                        }
        }
```

As per this code I should see only one mail because the Application exists, however I am seeing 8 mails(for each file it is iterating).  Why application is not quitting ? I want to kill the application at once.

It is a console application.

Comment: Maybe this code is executed in a separated thread and an exception is happening.

Comment: Yes the code above in the code which BackgroundWorker is executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment.Exit is what was needed.

Comment: This is not logical giving its in the question

Comment: @MicahArmantrout What ? Your comment does not make any sense. I asked how to kill the application immediately and Environment.Exit does it.

Comment: How can you give a answer when you have already shown that in the question. This explains nothing

Comment: @MicahArmantrout you are asking how can I answer my own question ? ohh looks like a bug ! you are really very funny.

Comment: This is correct, but does not explain why it's correct. Hans posted a solid answer with the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

> It is a console application

Which means that Application.Exit() will have no effect, it only closes opened Winform forms.  With the side effect that closing the main form then causes the message loop to exit.  Which completes the Application.Run() call, which completes the Main() method and that terminates the app.

A console mode app doesn't have any windows nor a message loop.  You should use Environment.Exit() instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start out with a basic understanding of the message pump.  What the UI thread is, at some very low level, is a while loop:

```
while(!shouldQuitapplication)
{
   Item nextItem = queue.GetNextItem();
   nextItem.Run();
}
```

Every time you call `Control.Invoke` you add a new item to the queue, every time a hook fires an event (mouse move, button click, etc.) it adds a new item to the queue.  All of the items are processes synchronously in the order they were received.

`Application.Exit` is essentially a way of ending the entire process once all of the existing items in the queue are finished.

Because you have a BackgroundWorker running it's doing "other stuff" in addition to whatever the UI thread is doing.  When you tell the UI thread to exit it will take some time to finish the remaining tasks in the queue.  (Which is why you see the background task performing a few more operations; that number will potentially vary.)

Note that the entire process will be torn down as soon as there are no more non-background threads.  The UI thread is a non-background thread, and the BackgroundWorker you're using uses a background thread.  When the UI thread ends the background worker will be stopped.  If you were manually creating a non-UI thread then it could potentially keep the process "up" and it wouldn't stop even after the UI thread stopped.  (That would be a step backward though, so clearly that's not helpful in this situation.)

The solution, as mentioned in another answer, is to ensure that the background task doesn't do anything once you call `Application.Exit`, by either calling `break`, `return`, or just structuring the loop differently such that it stops on an invalid item.